# Pass value from DataGridView to Textbox with searching in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which displays rows of table containing information in 4 columns. There are 4 textboxes used to input data to the datagridview. I have implemented a search feature (code below) to search for data in table. The thing I want is if I have searched an ID (for example, 123855) and the datagridview displays only one row with ID 123855, the value of 3 other columns is passed to the 3 other textboxes.

```
void SearchBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    koneksi.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from mahasiswa where nim like '"+searchBox.Text+"%' or nim like'%"+searchBox.Text+"' or nim like '%"+searchBox.Text+"%' ", koneksi);
    da.Fill(dt);
    Tabel.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    koneksi.Close();
}
```

How should I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: The simple logic would be, once you retrieved the data from the database based on the value of textbox (let say ID, 123855), you should check for how many rows are there in the table. If it's only one row then you should get the values from the row for other 3 columns and set them to the other 3 text boxes.

Comment: What would you display in the text boxes if more than one (1) item were returned from the search? In addition, if this is a search the user typed into the text boxes, then updating those same text boxes as the user types may be undesirable. It is not difficult to get the values from the cells in a `DataGridView` the question is which cells do you want to display in which text boxes?

Comment: @JohnG The search box is only for search for ID (only one column). If I searched for ID 123855 and the table displayed the row containing ID 123855 and the other 3 columns, I want the value of the other 3 columns passed to the 3 textboxes.

Comment: Hmm… that did not really answer my question. If there is only one row in the `DataGridView` then, to get the values from that row, you could use something like: `textBox1.Text = DatagridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value` to get the value in column 0, `.Cells[1].Value` to get the value from column 1… etc.. the posted answer shows this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged** event :

```
 private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null && dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index > -1)
     {
         string value1 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value != null ? dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() : "";
         textBox1.Text = value1; 

         string value2 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value != null ?  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() : "";
         textBox2.Text = value2;
         .
         .
         .
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code is working. But I put the IF statement in my SearchBoxTextChanged method. It won't work if it is put in CurrentCellChanged method.